# Show title of currently active tab from chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm a complete beginner at javascript.
I don't understand howto use  chrome.windows.get

What I want to do is:

1. Grab the current tab's title
2. using chrome.windows.get or anything that will work.
3. when the button (showbtn) is clicked
4. store this title to the div : showurl

popup.js followed by popup.html

```js
function output2() {
//internal variable el
el1 = document.getElementById('showurl');
chrome.windows.get(integer windowId, object getInfo, function callback)
}
document.getElementById('showbtn').addEventListener('click', output2);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Popup</title>
    <link href="popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>show url</h1>
    <div role="main">
      <form>
 <div id="showurl"></div>
        <button id="showbtn">Show Url title!</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved,
Achieved by using the getSelected method:

```js
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) { // null defaults to current window
  var title = tab.title;

  el1 = document.getElementById('showurl');
  el1.innerHTML = title;
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

Press `crtl + shift + i` to open dev tools. Go to console and type `document.title`.

Comment: This does not help with accessing the information from the Chrome extension.